# Search for all Python files in PyCharm, excluding test files

Tags: python, pycharm

I love using PyCharm's [Find in Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#find_in_project) tool, which allows me to search for text across the entire project. I know I can use the "File mask" filter to exclude certain file types from being searched.

I want to search across all Python files, excluding test files. That is, file names that start with `test`.

What I know:

- How to search across all Python files: `*.py`
- How to search across all files besides test files: `!test*.py`

How can I combine these to search across all Python files, besides these test files?

Comment: I don't understand. You say `What I know... How to search across all files besides test files: !test*.py`, but your question is `How can I combine these to search across all Python files, besides these test files?` Isn't that just the second thing you stated that you already know how to do?

Comment: I know how to search across all files (py, js, md, txt, etc.) but I only want to search across py files without the test files.

Comment: But that's what this does, right? `!test*.py` How is what you're looking for different than this?